# Remove Perl modules from CPAN on Mac

Tags: perl, module, cpan, bioperl

As far as I know it is required to run CPAN with sudo on Mac

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

to install new modules. Theoretically, a module can be removed by deleting it from the Perl folders.

My question is: Where are Perl modules put when installed from CPAN **with** 'sudo' and **without** 'sudo'? I installed BioPerl both ways and it seemed to work. Did I mess anything up by installing it with sudo and without?

Thank you for a little help in the confusing Perl world.

Comment: Do not run `cpan` with sudo. The tests will be run with superuser privileges, that is a bad idea. Instead [configure the `make_install_make_command` and `mbuild_install_build_command` options](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#Config_Variables) to only elevate when it is needed - namely for installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see where a module got installed with `perldoc -l <module>`.  That location is entirely dependent on your specific Perl installation, but you can see where the "standard" locations are by examining the `@INC` lines in the output of `perl -V`.