# How do I uninstall Perl modules?

Tags: perl, git-submodules

I installed some Perl modules in my Linux machine. If I enter `perldoc perllocal` it shows a list of Perl modules installed in my machine, but now I don't need those Perl modules, so I want to remove them.

Does anyone know how to uninstall or remove those modules installed in Linux (debian 2.6.26)?

Comment: *HOW* did you install the modules? Did you use CPAN or CPANPLUS, yum or apt or something similar? Did you download the modules and install them manually?

Comment: I downloaded the needed modules from CPAN and installed it by, perl Makefile.PL, make, make test and make install commands.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045917/remove-perl-modules-from-cpan-on-mac

Comment: The new hipness is pm-uninstall: http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-pmuninstall/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Perl installers are just that... installers.  They don't verify that they're not overwriting existing files, and they don't record precisely what they install.  Therefore, they cannot uninstall.  If you want a proper packaging system, you can't use the Perl installers.

Comment: What a radical thing to say. Of the >1300 distributions I have installed, only a handful are not cleanly reversible with the [primary recording mechanism](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils::Packlist).

Comment: How is "the truth" radical?  From the beginning, the Perl installers were never meant as uninstallers.  If you had been around since the beginning, you would know that.  Just because it *mostly* works with simple distros doesn't mean you should be able to count on it for *every* distro like a proper packaging system.

Answer (score 5):

If you use CPANPLUS to install a module, you can (at least in theory) also use it to uninstall it:

```
$ cpanp
...
> u Unwanted::Module
...
> q
$
```

The older CPAN module does not support an uninstall option.  And, as [Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz) notes, uninstalling modules is not always reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Use cpanp (its uninstall is *not* limited to cpanplus-installed modules), or see [ExtUtils::Packlist](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils%3a%3aPacklist)'s modrm example.

Uninstall tools have historically been not readily provided because the install process is not robustly reversible, as Randal cautions.

Comment: An uninstall tool similar to `modrm` was readily provided in the [CPAN FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20070710130823/www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_delete_Perl_modules) until it got "depublished" for some bullshit reason.

Comment: You can't just sprinkle magic fairy dust on something that doesn't work to make it work.  Fundamentally, there is no registration of path names, so any two modules in the CPAN can easily install to the same place, and some even do.

Answer (score 2):

As I've mentioned [somewhere else on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778134/468327), my answer is to just leave them. There are VERY few Perl modules large enough to take up any actual space on you system. I'm not saying don't try if you really need the space, but if you don't ... its not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [App::pmuninstall](https://metacpan.org/release/App-pmuninstall)

> DESCRIPTION
>
> App::pmuninstall is a fast module uninstaller. delete files from
>   .packlist.
>
> App::cpanminus and, App::cpanoutdated with a high affinity.

Comment: Here's the proper link: https://metacpan.org/pod/App::pmuninstall

Answer (score 0):

I tried cpanp uninstall and it didn't work for me.  I did find success using App::pmuninstall.

pm-uninstall [options] Module ...

[pm-uninstall - Uninstall modules - metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-pmuninstall/bin/pm-uninstall)